# gwt typerror ( cannot call method 'X' of null )

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I have a very simple GWT app, containing a simple rpc callback for a database operation. 
All it does is a retrieve a string from the database. This works fine locally. It retrieves the string trough a callback and displays it on the screen.

But when I deploy it to appengine, it doesn't work and gives me the error ' gwt typerror ( cannot call method 'X' of null ) '. I've tried debugging, logging etc but it gives me nothing and I'm desperately lost.

```
        EntityService.Util.getInstance().getEntityName(
                Function.getHash("john"), Function.getHash("name"),
                Function.getHash("english"), new AsyncCallback<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String result) {
                        l.setText(result);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        l.setText(caught.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

U guys have any clue what could be going on, or why I'm getting this error on appengine?
I've tried to only to connect the database on appengine deployed trough a callback and  this works fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: object l is a label object that displays the string on the screen

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to debug such errors if you try using either of following solutions before pushing into appengine -

Solution 1 - Compile you application in `pretty` mode as long as you are not pushing into prod mode.

Pretty mode allows you easier debugging in web mode. The exceptions are readable.

Solution 2 - Integrate `Webmode Exception handling` - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions

Both the solution add some runtime performance penalty and should be used in dev cycles. Once you have polished tested application Turn webmode exception and pretty compilation off.